# Android web views inside horizontal scroll view stretching

Tags: android, webview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a detail view with horizontal scrollview and I insert some web view to this horizontal scrollview.

Here is the xml code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And here is code where I put web view to this horizontal scroll view:

```
HorizontalScrollView scroll = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal);

        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

        SearchJobDetailWebView test1 = new SearchJobDetailWebView(this, middleData.get(0).getExportUrl());
        linear.addView(test1.setWebView());

        SearchJobDetailWebView test2 = new SearchJobDetailWebView(this, middleData.get(0).getExportUrl());
        linear.addView(test2.setWebView());

        SearchJobDetailWebView test3 = new SearchJobDetailWebView(this, middleData.get(0).getExportUrl());
        linear.addView(test3.setWebView());
```

Problem is that web views are stretched in horizontal scrollview. (Webview width is a half part of display). What is wrong ?
thanks a lot

Comment: remember that using addview(View child) adds the view with the default parameters.
Also you mention that Webview is half part of the display and you show 3 webviews, I quite dont understand that part (since that would be 1.5 display or 3 webviews in just half of the display)

Comment: Two web views are on the current display (each of them occupies half of display) and the third web view is next to them. I can't set horizontal scroll view so that each web view is displayed across the display ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to try to answer your question for what I understood. You have 3 `webviews` and 2 are on the screen, the 3rd is off the screen but should be visible whenever you scroll horizontally.
Well `WebViews` use horizontal scrolling so if you have 3 webvies whenever you are swipping your finger its not the main `Scrollview` that is taking the touch, its the `webview`. I havent tested this yet but what I would do is disable the horizontal scrolling in each `WebView` by using:

```
myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: ok here is the explanation:http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3149/imagelgl.jpg This is my problem

Comment: did you try my solution? but if you were thinking on keeping the horizontal scrolling for each webview then what you are trying to achieve the way you are trying to its impossible, since every WebView has its own horizontal scrollview and the system takes the swipe of finger as if it was part of of horizontal scrolling of a webview instead of the main scollview

Comment: yes I tried and did not work. I need to do a "horizontal paging" (something like iPhone horizontal paging) ...